# I'm getting an error while trying to configure MySQL 8.0.33

Tags: mysql, configuration, shutdown

```
Beginning configuration step: Stopping the server

Setting innodb_fast_shutdown to do a clean shutdown (a full purge and a change buffer merge before shutting down).  
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe --defaults-extra-file="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\48cc9066-4c8a-41f2-bc8c-1978be995213.ini" --user=root --default-auth=caching_sha2_password --host=localhost --port=3306 -e"SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0"...
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Process for mysql, with ID 9344, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
There was an error trying to set innodb_fast_shutdown to do a clean shutdown.  

Executing mysqladmin shutdown to do a clean shutdown.  

Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqladmin.exe --defaults-extra-file="C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\48cc9066-4c8a-41f2-bc8c-1978be995213.ini" --user=root --default-auth=caching_sha2_password --host=localhost --port=3306 shutdown...
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
Process for mysqladmin, with ID 25612, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
There was an error trying to perform a clean shutdown.
Stopping MySQL Server instance...
Found Windows service for the server instance. Stopping MySQL service...
MySQL service stopped successfully...
Ended configuration step: Stopping the server

Beginning configuration step: Writing configuration file

Saving my.ini configuration file...
Saved my.ini configuration file.
Ended configuration step: Writing configuration file

Beginning configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Attempting to delete a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall delete rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306

Deleted 1 rule(s).
Ok.


Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80! on port 3306.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 3306" protocol=TCP localport=3306 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Adding a Windows Firewall rule for MySQL80! on port 33060.
Attempting to add a Windows Firewall rule with command: netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="Port 33060" protocol=TCP localport=33060 dir=in action=allow
Ok.


Successfully added the Windows Firewall rule.
Ended configuration step: Updating Windows Firewall rules

Beginning configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Attempting to grant the required filesystem permissions to the 'NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService' account.
Granted permissions to the data directory.
Adding new service
New service added
Ended configuration step: Adjusting Windows service

Beginning configuration step: Starting the server

Attempting to start service MySQL80!...
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 22128
InnoDB initialization has started.
InnoDB initialization has ended.
CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
Successfully started service MySQL80!.
Waiting until a connection to MySQL Server 8.0.33 can be established (with a maximum of 10 attempts)...
Retry 1: Attempting to connect to Mysql@localhost:3306 with user root with a password...
Successfully connected to MySQL Server 8.0.33.
Ended configuration step: Starting the server

Beginning configuration step: Creating user accounts

Attempting to Add New MySQL Users
An error occurred trying to add new users to the MySQL database (see log).
Ended configuration step: Creating user accounts
```

Every time I try to configure the SQL server, it fails as "Creating Users". I've tried to use easier passwords without special characters. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it keeps saying that my "MYSQL80" value is already in use as a Windows Server name? I don't know. I really need the help, please

Comment: "Beginning configuration step:" -- Is this _you_ telling us of manual steps you applied?  Or is this a message from some script?

Comment: "An error occurred trying to add new users to the MySQL database (see log)."  and what does the log say?   you don't identify anywhere what you are actually doing to configure the server; this seems to be some script or tool?  find the log it refers to and see what the error was.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.